# Policies Array Class-Design wrapper

Tags: c++, arrays, class-design, policy

i want to write an wrapper for different Array Classes with different Policies.

For example:

```
typedef ArrayType<useValArray,StdAllocator> Array; // one global assignment
```

I want to use the class like a blitz++ Array

for example:

```
Array<double,2> x(2,2); //maps the Array to an Valarray or to a Blitz++ Array
Array<double,2> x2(5,6);
```

is this Posible? Which technics i need to realise that?

Answer (score 1):

I think not in way you describe (at least because of template parameters) but ...

Short time ago STL wrapper for existing array was discussed
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713657/wrapping-dynamic-array-into-stl-boost-container). I suggest you should look array_proxy recommendation as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but I think you're asking about 'templated typedefs' which aren't directly supported in C++, [but can be mimicked.](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm) Also note, templated typdefs are included in C++0x.