# how to have vector data point to array

Tags: c++, vector, c++builder

I'm building a c++ class that wraps a C-style api for database access. Its hierarchical, where each survey line includes many channels of data. Each channel is stored and passed as an array of many points. I would like to use vectors in my class, but the api gives me a pointer to the array in memory and copying the data into my vector manually and then out again after processing doesn't make sense.

Is there another class or a descendent of vector with the ability to accept a pointer to the data? I briefly considered writing my own vector class, but I'm a noob at c++ and I got scared off after looking at the vector template.

Comment: If you're using C++11, how about `std::unique_ptr<point_type[]>`?

Comment: If you don't want to copy data, perhaps vector isn't the right choice. Why exactly do you need it?

Comment: Echoing what @jrok said, what are you trying to achieve?  For example, are you looking to use the standard algorithms?  If so, you can just use the raw array pointers as arguments since they too are iterators.  I, too, prefer to use a `vector` over a naked array but it doesn't appear to make sense to do so in your use case.

Comment: I didn't know that I could use an array pointer in the standard algorithms. That's exactly what I want. I'm just finding my way in the STL, which is a big hill to climb. cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting my comment in "answer" form ...

Since copying the array is not option, a `vector` is probably not what you are looking for.  If all you are looking to do is use the standard algorithms you can just use the raw array pointers as arguments since they too are iterators, e.g.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 2, -1, 7, 6 };

  int * const begin = a;
  int * const end   = a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

  std::sort(begin, end);
  std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

results in the following:

```
$ g++ foo.cpp ; ./a.out 
-1
2
6
7
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple example. This is clearly the way to go. Cheers.

Comment: And presumably `std::for_each(begin, end, FunctionAcceptingInts)` which stems from my previous answer. It just cuts out the `vector<>` in the middle...

Answer (score 0):

It is not so hard to assign an array into a vector. It does require copying but this is a standard function of `std::vector<>`. Something like this might fit the bill;

```
using namespace std;

void WriteInt (int i) { cout << " " << i; }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int myInts[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> myVectorOfInts(5);
    myVectorOfInts.assign(&myInts[0], &myInts[5]);
    for_each(myVectorOfInts.begin(), myVectorOfInts.end(), WriteInt);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

In your case, copying an array of pointers into a vector is very fast, since a pointer takes up only one memory location. If you were copying complex objects, that would be another matter...

Comment: A previous answer - deleted I guess - achieved this by using the form of the `vector` constructor that accepted iterators.  One of the goals posted in the question is not to perform a copy.  All @marcp wanted to do was to apply standard algorithms to the array, which can be achieved by directly passing pointers to array elements as the iterator arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the answer to your question; https://stackoverflow.com/a/15141661/1546600
You can create an empty vector and assign an existing array to it.